# Getting better ContourPlot3D results

Tags: plotting

I want to plot nicely the surface determined by the equation $$
\frac{x}{y+z}+\frac{y}{x+z}+\frac{z}{x+y}=0.
$$

To do this, I use :

```
ContourPlot3D[
 x/(y + z) + y/(x + z) + z/(x + y) == 0, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 
  20}, {z, -20, 20}]
```

but get this output:

[image]

I am well aware that the equation is discontinuous when $y+z=0, x+z = 0$ or $x+y =0$.

So is there a way to improve the output of Contour3D with such functions?

---

**Different approach:**

I tried to solve the equation for $z$ to get at least one leaf of the surface by

```
Solve[x/(y + z) + y/(x + z) + z/(x + y) == 0, z] // Simplify
```

the only real solution of which is the expression:

$\frac{1}{6} \left(-2 (x+y)-\frac{2 2^{1/3} \left(2 x^2+7 x y+2 y^2\right)}{\left(-20 x^3+3 x^2 y+3 x y^2-20 y^3+3 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{16 x^6+8 x^5 y+43 x^4 y^2+106 x^3 y^3+43 x^2 y^4+8 x y^5+16 y^6}\right)^{1/3}}+2^{2/3} \left(-20 x^3+3 x^2 y+3 x y^2-20 y^3+3 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{16 x^6+8 x^5 y+43 x^4 y^2+106 x^3 y^3+43 x^2 y^4+8 x y^5+16 y^6}\right)^{1/3}\right).$

The plot of the latter, again in $x \in (-20,20), y \in (-20,20)$, is more convenient[image]:

However, I prefer to somehow avoid solving the equation because:

1. In other scenarios even Mathematica wouldn't find solution.
2. Even if it finds it finds solution it may not be the only one and thus only part of the real surface will be plot.

P.S. I am using *Mathematica 7.0*

Comment: Try `PlotPoints->100`

Comment: Thank you. With parameter 100 I waited 10 minutes and didn't get a result. With a parameter 50 the time was probably about a minute but the computer lagged much when trying to rotate the plot. With a parameter 20  I could say that the result is better. Thank you.

Comment: `ContourPlot3D[
 Numerator[
   x/(y + z) + y/(x + z) + z/(x + y) //
    Together] == 0,
 {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, {z, -20, 20}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon What does this Together mean? connecting discontinuities?

Comment: Look at `x/(y + z) + y/(x + z) + z/(x + y) // Together` or read the documentation for [`Together`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Together.html)

Comment: What a cool plot (with Bob Hanlon's fix). It's also advisable to add an `Evaluate` around the whole thing: `ContourPlot3D[Evaluate[Numerator[x/(y + z) + y/(x + z) + z/(x + y) // Together] == 0], ...]`